# How to fix argument of type is is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, filter, types, reduce

I'm trying to filter my array of objects in react type script.
Got this error.Here is my interface , state and function

TS2345: Argument of type '(prev: IBudget, current: IBudget) => IBudget | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: IBudget, currentValue: IBudget, currentIndex: number, array: IBudget[]) => IBudget'.
Type 'IBudget | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IBudget'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IBudget'.

```
 export interface IBudget {
    title?:string,
    price?:number,
    date?: Date,
}

const [expenses,setExpenses] = useState<IBudget[]>([])

  if (!isEmpty(expenses)){
        const max = expenses.reduce((prev , current)=> {
            if( prev !== undefined) {
                if (prev.price !== undefined && current.price !== undefined){
                    return (prev.price > current.price) ? prev : current
                }
            }
        }) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you didn't pass an initial value to the `reduce` function, and given your implementation you could pass the first argument of the `expenses` array

```
const max = expenses.reduce((prev, current) => {
 if (prev !== undefined) {
   if (prev.price !== undefined && current.price !== undefined) {
     return prev.price > current.price ? prev : current;
   }
 }
}, expenses[0]);
```

after you do that you probably will have another error saying that the `previous` or the `current` types do not match with `undefined`. And this would be because you have `if's` that could potentially not be entered right? and if that happens your code will return `undefined` to the next interaction.

In order to fix that you need to make sure that some value is returned to the next iteration, as below:

```
const max = expenses.reduce((prev, current) => {
 if (prev !== undefined) {
   if (prev.price !== undefined && current.price !== undefined) {
     return prev.price > current.price ? prev : current;
   }
 }

 // here you might have to adjust to your needs
 return current;
}, expenses[0]);
```

Comment: Adding 'return current' fixed it. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

The type definition of `reduce` will automatically set the return type to the type of array - `number[]` is assumed to reduce to `number`.

You can override this by passing a `initialValue` of the same type as you expect the return to be, or by setting it using generics (or both):

```
[1,2,3].reduce<number | string>(...)
```

In your case, it's unclear what your desired result is. Do you intend to have `undefined` possibly be returned? If not, you need to handle the cases where your 2 `if` statements do not pass, since the absence of a `return` is what is causing the `undefined` type inference.

If you do want the possibility of undefined, you could simply set the type, and pass in an `initialValue`:

```
const max = expenses.reduce<IBudget | undefined>((prev , current)=> {
  if( prev !== undefined) {
    if (prev.price !== undefined && current.price !== undefined){
      return (prev.price > current.price) ? prev : current
    }
  }
}, undefined)
```